# Facebook tab application cannot access photos of Fan Page

Tags: facebook

I am the admin of a Fan Page, where users will upload a  photo to Wall. 
I have installed a Facebook tab application on that page,which will get the Wall posts and extracts the pictures.However, I am not able to render the photos in my tab.

It dies with  403 Forbidden Error.
Anybody has faced such issue?

I have checked with 'user_likes' and 'manage_pages' but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The 403 error is not a Facebook permission error. That error is saying that Facebook cannot access your server. There must be an issue with your server that is causing Facebook to not be able to connect to it.

Comment: the canvas application works fine.Only when i use it as a tab,facebooj restricts access to the uploaded files.So I dont think there is an issue with accessing my server.I think its one of those obscure restrictions on tab applications.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, resolved it using absolute paths to the images (with http://)